# Replace all NaN in specific row with same value - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, replace, nan

I have an array (data2winner) that looks like this:

Columns 1 through 6

```
1.0894    1.1923    1.0238    1.0625    1.0222    0.9701
1.0000    1.2419    1.2093    0.9412    0.9783    1.0923
1.0379       NaN    1.0000    1.0417    1.0667    1.0000
```

Columns 7 through 12

```
0.9661    0.9568    1.0400    0.8519    0.8675    0.9821
0.7895    1.0000       NaN    1.0000    1.1250    0.8182
1.0667    0.7714       NaN    1.0000    0.9383    1.1111
```

I want to replace all NaN in the same row (e.g. row 3) with the same value, lets say 0.5, such that the output looks like this:

Columns 1 through 6

```
1.0894    1.1923    1.0238    1.0625    1.0222    0.9701
1.0000    1.2419    1.2093    0.9412    0.9783    1.0923
1.0379       **0.5**    1.0000    1.0417    1.0667    1.0000
```

Columns 7 through 12

```
0.9661    0.9568    1.0400    0.8519    0.8675    0.9821
0.7895    1.0000       NaN    1.0000    1.1250    0.8182
1.0667    0.7714       **0.5**    1.0000    0.9383    1.1111
```

I know I can replace all NaN in my matrix by 0.5 using this:

> `data2winner(isnan(data2winner)) = 0.5`

So i thought using

> `data2winner(isnan(data2winner(3,:))) = 0.5`

would solve my problem, but it does not work. Does anybody have an idea how to solve my problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isnan(data2winner(3,:))` gives you a logical array of ones and zeros where `NaNs` are present or not respectively in the third row. Then, you were needed to index into the third row of the input matrix and select the columns that had `NaNs` (ones from `isnan` output) and set them to `0.5`. Your mistake was indexing into the complete matrix instead of only the third row.

Thus, this should do it -

```
row_id = 3;
data2winner(row_id,isnan(data2winner(row_id,:))) = 0.5
```